# cascade delete from many to many relationship

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

i have the following relational database model

[image]

Both `authors and books`  table has one to many relationship with book_author table.Also they have cascade delete update relationship.If i delete any entry in `authors or books` table ,corresponding data from `book_author` table also gets deleted.But the problem is if i delete an author ,there should be no book in `books` table of that author.How i can make it so that if i delete an author ,corresponding  books of that author will also gets deleted from `Books` table and vise versa.

Comment: I hope this video will help you to resolve your problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LuC06E6CueI

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done using relationships settings only, you need to add deleting logic to frontend (to `After Del Confirm` form's event) or, better, create data macro on backend side (`After Delete` data macro)

Comment: i am looking for examples how to use data macro to do this?can u shed some light on this or provide some source.I looked in msdn..it was not very specific to my problem

Comment: Search for examples of using data macro, quite often MSDN is not the best source for such kind information. For instance [this tutorial](http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/after-delete.html) may help.